# gdb with stange error: ??. what does it mean?

Tags: c, gdb

I compile my programm with gcc and then I run gcc on the a.out file.
When I run the programm inside gdb then, I am getting this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff118 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xbffff118 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

What does this mean?
Also before i, when is was trying to run the program normally I got this error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./benchmark terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So i read that this is a protection for buffer overflows, i double checked everything an there should be everything fine so i disabled this using the flag:

```
-fno-stack-protector
```

edit: I am not posting the code since I want to figure out how to use gdb rather than getting just my code working. so I am new to gdb but I used it a couple of times with success now. Still i cannot figure out what ?? means, in what cases can gdb point me not the the corresponding call in my code, that causes the error and why is the address of frame 1 0x0?

Comment: It means the application segfaulted. Judging by your comments perhaps you are overwriting the stack or writing beyond it. Also it would help if you compiled your application with warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) and debugging symbols (`-g`). Also why would you want to disable the stack protection mechanism? It's there to ensure your programs are safe.

Comment: i used the -g flag since the begining, i used -Wall and -Wextra now and eliminating all warnings, but still the same...

Comment: If you use `-g` GDB should be able to give you the names and lines of the functions that fail.

Comment: ...a Question about stackoverflow on stackoverflow! :)

Comment: i used it and it could give me the name, used it before in as different programm and it worked there

Answer (score 5):

When you get a junk backtrace like that, it almost certainly means that your stack was smashed somehow, and the actual return addresses and stack frame pointers have been overwritten.

The value `0xbffff118` is almost certainly an address in your stack.  I believe that on many x86 Linux compilers, the compiler starts the stack at virtual address `0xc0000000`, and it grows downwards from there, so any addresses starting with `0xbfff` are very likely stack addresses.

Ordinarily, the instruction pointer should never be inside the stack.  The way that that typically happens is that a value pointing into the stack overwrites a return address stored in the stack, and then when the current function returns, it returns to the overwritten value.  If the stack is non-executable, like it should be, this will raise a signal immediately; if somehow the stack is executable, then it may not crash until several instructions later, unless you're being maliciously exploited, in which case you're going to have a bad time.

Once your stack is smashed, the `backtrace` command is not going to be useful, as you found out.  The best way to figure out what's going on from there is to manually inspect the stack and search for probably return addresses and frame pointers.  You can use the `x` command to dump a memory region (run `help x` for details).  I like to use the `x/<NUMBER>wx` to dump as 4-byte hex values.  So, here's how to dump a bunch of data starting at the stack pointer `$esp`:

```
(gdb) x/64wx $esp
0xbffff7c0: 0x00000073  0xbffff9e9  0x0000000b  0x00000012
0xbffff7d0: 0xbffff9e8  0x0be04aa0  0xbffff7f8  0x000018aa
0xbffff7e0: 0x0be04aa0  0xbffff9e8  0x00000000  0x00000002
0xbffff7f0: 0xbffff9e7  0x09a0bb10  0xbffff818  0x000018aa
0xbffff800: 0x09a0bb10  0xbffff9e7  0x00000002  0x0000000e
0xbffff810: 0xbffff9e6  0x015377f0  0xbffff838  0x000018aa
0xbffff820: 0x015377f0  0xbffff9e6  0x00000008  0x00000011
0xbffff830: 0xbffff9e5  0x01537860  0xbffff858  0x000018aa
0xbffff840: 0x01537860  0xbffff9e5  0x00000003  0x0000000f
0xbffff850: 0xbffff9e4  0x001ddbc0  0xbffff878  0x000018aa
0xbffff860: 0x001ddbc0  0xbffff9e4  0x00000018  0x00000017
0xbffff870: 0xbffff9e3  0x00177c50  0xbffff898  0x000018aa
0xbffff880: 0x00177c50  0xbffff9e3  0xbffff8b8  0x00000000
0xbffff890: 0xbffff9e2  0x00176050  0xbffff8b8  0x000018aa
0xbffff8a0: 0x00176050  0xbffff9e2  0xbffff9e1  0x0000000c
0xbffff8b0: 0xbffff9e1  0x00174920  0xbffffb08  0x00001b8a
```

Here, `$esp` is `0xbffff7c0`, and `$eip` is `0x00001870` (which I got using the `p/x $eip` command, but it can also be seen with `info regs` to get all of the registers).  So, every stack frame will be a pointer higher into the stack (`0xbfff....`) followed by an address similar to `0x00001870`.  Looking for these in the memory dump, we can be pretty sure that these are stack frames:

```
0xbffff7f8  0x000018aa
0xbffff818  0x000018aa
0xbffff838  0x000018aa
(etc.)
```

This is an example I grabbed from a highly recursive program I had lying around, so that's why the return addresses are all the same.  Once you find a few good stack frames that haven't been smashed, you can just follow the frame pointers yourself:

```
(gdb) x/2wx 0xbffff7f8
0xbffff7f8: 0xbffff818  0x000018aa
(gdb) x/2wx 0xbffff818
0xbffff818: 0xbffff838  0x000018aa
(gdb) x/2wx 0xbffff838
0xbffff838: 0xbffff858  0x000018aa
(gdb) x/2wx 0xbffff858
0xbffff858: 0xbffff878  0x000018aa
...
```

And then if you want to convert instruction addresses into symbol names, you can again use the `x` command, and if you have debug symbols, gdb will happily print the symbol name:

```
(gdb) x 0x000018aa
0x18aa <add_word+154>:  0x5d18c483
```

That's a quick primer on how to get an actual useful stack trace when your stack has been smashed.  Of course, it's best to avoid this in the first place.  I highly recommend that you compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (and also `-pedantic` if you can), and of course don't use `-fno-stack-protector` unless you have a really, *really* good reason to do so.

Comment: great answere with this i will have some stuff to tryout and learn!

Answer (score 0):

once the stack is garbled there is no way to tell what happened...
in pure c it is typically kind of hard to smash the stack, are you doing any assembly or using gotos / labels? those are the typical routes I have seen...

basically what happens is the return address gets overwritten, and when you try to return to that garbage address the stack doesn't make sense.

Comment: i am neither doing assyembly nor any gotos, what i fugured out with printf is that the probramm is crashing inside a for loop, but not always at the same point

Comment: oh yeah printf can do it, if you use any variadic function you can end up with mismatched stack push/pops... but compilers typically read that and give you a warning.